# Term for limitless temporal scope of digital information

Tags: single-word-requests

Social media and digital information storage together have created a new kind of archive in which even arcane details of individuals' behaviour and attitudes cannot easily be forgotten or erased.

What is the best term to describe the *limitless temporal scope* of contemporary digital information?  A term that expresses not only how digital records simply amass, but also how the digital archive is persistent/everlasting.

*My digital footprint is **???***

Comment: Do you understand how easily digital media CAN forget?

Comment: *limitless temporal scope = **eternal***

Comment: There are alternatives - ***ageless***, for example. Or to borrow a term from modern cosmology, ***temporally unbounded***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please don't answer questions in comments. Any or all of those would be an answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I voted to ***close*** the question, so on principle I wouldn't want to answer. I just didn't want to leave the OP thinking the only available answer was "omnitemporal" below (now changed to reflect my first suggestion above).

Comment: @DJClayworth This is a marginal SWR which could easily be closable. Offering a single word alone as an answer is poor form too, so it is very appropriate to just offer suggestion words in comments.

Comment: The problem with offering answers to off-topic questions in comments is that people get used to the idea that they will get an answer if they post a question here, even if it is off topic. So they keep posting off topic questions.

Comment: You really want to use the phrase "digital footprint"? Is that part of the "challenge" here?

Comment: @TRomano - er, not especially... although I like the way it resonates with dinosaurs' footprints.

Answer (score 2):

From the standpoint of “cannot be erased” is the option

> [***indelible***](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/indelible)
>
> that cannot be eliminated, forgotten, changed, or the like:
>   *the indelible memories of war; the indelible influence of a great teacher.*
>
> <sup><sub>[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/indelible)</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks - a very good suggestion!  I like how it nods not only at 'everlasting' but also at the irremovability of digital information.  I also like the fact that its religious associations are minimal! Very strong contender for green tick...

Answer (score 0):

**Eternal**. [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eternal):

> 1. Lasting or existing forever; without end.

Eternal comes from the Latin *[aeternus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aeternus)*, and is commonly used to refer to timelessness.

Comment: That's kind of a far out term (what is its frequency?) when the very normal 'eternal' already exists.

Comment: But fine. I change my answer to eternal.